# Node-RED Twitter out throws Error 32 when passing msg.params

Tags: json, twitter, node-red

I'm doing a Visual Rec app on nodered and want to tweet out the resultas as a reply to the original tweet (that reuqested de vis rec).
If I only put the username at the beginning sometimes twitter doesn't show it to the user because of the "in_reply_to_status_id" field being empty, so I need to pass thos parameters though msg.params.
When I do that, the tweet out node throws:

"Error: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized, API message: {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}"

If I "//" the msg.params line, it tweets just fine.

My params line goes like this:

```
msg.params=[{"tweet.in_reply_to_status_id":context.global.tweet.id},{"tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name":context.global.tweet.user.screen_name}];
```

I also tried without the "in_reply_to_screen_name" field (not sure if that's absolutely necessary for the reply), and without the "tweet." part as well.

Any help?!

Answer (score 0):

OK, this worked:

msg.params={"tweet.in_reply_to_status_id":context.global.tweet.id,"tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name":context.global.tweet.user.screen_name};

Thanks Timothy from work!